# How do I add a title and axis labels to Seaborn Heatmap?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I want to add a title to a seaborn heatmap. Using Pandas and iPython Notebook

code is below,

```
a1_p = a1.pivot_table( index='Postcode', columns='Property Type', values='Count', aggfunc=np.mean, fill_value=0)

sns.heatmap(a1_p, cmap="YlGnBu")
```

the data is pretty straight forward:

```
In [179]: a1_p

Out [179]:
Property Type   Flat    Terraced house  Unknown
Postcode            
E1  11  0   0
E14 12  0   0
E1W 6   0   0
E2  6   0   0
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`heatmap` is an `axes`-level function, so you should be able to use just `plt.title` or `ax.set_title`:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import os
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.randn(10,12)

ax = plt.axes()
sns.heatmap(data, ax = ax)

ax.set_title('lalala')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 40):

To give title for seaborn heatmap use

```
plt.title("Enter your title", fontsize =20)
```

or 
`ax.set(title = "Enter your title")`

```
import seaborn as sns # for data visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # for data visualization

flight = sns.load_dataset('flights') # load flights datset from GitHub seaborn repository

# reshape flights dataeset in proper format to create seaborn heatmap
flights_df = flight.pivot('month', 'year', 'passengers') 

ax = sns.heatmap(flights_df) # create seaborn heatmap


plt.title('Heatmap of Flighr Dataset', fontsize = 20) # title with fontsize 20
plt.xlabel('Years', fontsize = 15) # x-axis label with fontsize 15
plt.ylabel('Monthes', fontsize = 15) # y-axis label with fontsize 15

plt.show()
```

**Output >>>**

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively `sns.plt.suptitle('lalala')` would work if you have multiple subplots.

Comment: Seaborn dropped exposure to matplotlib.pyplot in their package, import `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and write `plt.suptitle('lalala')` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the same xlabel and ylabel and title from **matplotlib.pyplot** library.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn

sn.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt="d")
plt.xlabel("Enter the X axis")
plt.ylabel("Enter the Y axis")
plt.title("Enter the Title")
plt.show()
```

**Note:** If you need bigger font, use fontsize in all those.